# YouTube iframe api won't play from click handler on iOS

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the Youtube iframe api to show a custom thumbnail and play button over an embedded video. It is working everywhere (including android) except for iOS, where I get "If playback doesn't begin shortly, try restarting your device" behind the thumbnail. If I hide the thumbnail, I can play the video using Youtube's play button (before using my controls) and the html5 play button (after using my controls)

I am aware of the restriction on autoplaying videos, but this should get around that because it is triggered by a click handler, and works on android which has the same restriction

```
function loadVideo(videoID, title, description, thumbUrl, waitPlay) {
    var playBtn = jQuery(".playerThumb");
    jQuery(".playerTitle").text(title);
    jQuery(".playerDesc").text(description);

    jQuery(".playerEmbed").replaceWith("<div id='video' class='playerEmbed'></div>");
    playBtn.css("background-image", "url(" + thumbUrl + ")").show().off('click').removeClass("ready");
    jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400, "swing", function(){});

    ytPlayer = new YT.Player('video', {
        videoId: videoID,
        playerVars: {
            rel: 0,
            showinfo: 0,
            autoplay: (waitPlay === true ? 0 : 1)
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onReady,
            'onError': function(e){console.error(e);},
            'onStateChange': function(e){if (e.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) jQuery(".playerThumb").fadeOut();}
        }
    });

    function onReady(e) {
        playBtn.click(function() {ytPlayer.playVideo();}).addClass("ready");
        if (waitPlay !== true) {
            if (ytPlayer.getPlayerState() == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                playBtn.hide();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get this to work on iOS? Is my only option to just use the default play button for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and found the solution.

It turns out that on iOS you can't overlay the youtube video with any div, the user needs to click directly on the youtube iframe for the video to start.